# Search results not showing up on "items" or "resultsPerPage" while existing in "totalResults"

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been trying to find channels on YouTube using the `Search.list` API endpoint's `type` `channel`.

And I get an empty `items` property; but the response indicates that there are results in `totalResults` and `0` results in `resultsPerPage`:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "iHuEFDsu11n1f_tDVzZYHXDlOIQ",
  "regionCode": "IL",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 4,
    "resultsPerPage": 0
  },
  "items": []
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please take the time to absorb [SO's recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) addressed to new users. You may take the [tour]; then do read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

You have to acknowledge is that the property `totalResults` is not reliable by its very specification (the emphasis below is mine):

> [**pageInfo.totalResults**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#pageInfo.totalResults) (integer)
>
> The total number of results in the result set. *Please note that the value is an approximation and may not represent an exact value.* In addition, the maximum value is 1,000,000.
>
> You should not use this value to create pagination links. Instead, use the `nextPageToken` and `prevPageToken` property values to determine whether to show pagination links.

This peculiarity of `totalResults` [is also confirmed officially](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155088389#comment2) by Google's staff.